# Exchange user can send through OWA, but not through Outlook 2007?

Tags: exchange-2003

Got a weird one.  I have one user in my domain of several hundred who is experiencing this problem.  His account can send and receive just fine when using OWA, but he can only receive (not send) when using Outlook.  All traffic is for internal recipients.

I have tried setting him up w/ a fresh install of Outlook, I've tried using a new computer w/ a fresh install of Outlook as well.  I have likewise tried removing the exchange features from his account and re-adding them (he's a new user, so losing the MB wasn't a big hit).  No joy on any of this.

On the Exchange server, I see the messages in the queue that's got the fully qualified name of the primary exchange server, and they're all listed as state of Retry.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be mailbox corruption at the server level. What occurs when the same non-working Outlook client(s) are connected to a different Exchange mailbox? If the other mailbox(es) connect successfully, then you may be facing the possible options of:

- Migrating the emails from the corrupt/damaged mailbox to a different mailbox
- Attempting a mail database repair at the server to correct the mailbox damage

The second option should be considered (maybe in read-only mode) even with the first option route.

Comment: It's user account specific, regardless of which outlook instance they're on, as I said in the problem.

Comment: Mailbox or user account? If it is user account, then it may be a rights issue where something is corrupted or inadvertently changed.

Comment: I assume user account, since as I said we tried removing all the exchange features from him and re-adding them, to no avail.

Comment: What happens when a different mailbox is assigned to the user account?

Comment: exact same thing.

Comment: It sounds like a user rights issue based on your descriptions. You might start by documenting all the group memberships and then removing the user from the groups for testing. There is also a chance that the user account is somehow corrupt where it may need to be recreated, if unrepairable.